# Can someone explain the parameter autovacuum_naptime?

Tags: postgresql

I read the explaination from official, But i'm still cant not understand the parameter well. Can someone explain the parameter autovacuum_naptime ? thanks a lot !

Comment: The word "nap" means "sleep". Does that help? If not, what are you having trouble with? Do you know what vacuuming is for and why it is useful to do it automatically? What part of the documentation needs more explanation?

Comment: yes , i know the autovacuum process of PG in some way, just as you say, for the begining ,i don't understand the word "nap" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the minimum time that postgresql wait between each auto vacuum.

Say for example you kept the default value of 1 minute, there will be at least 1 minute without vacuum after the last one finished.

The time is for each database separately and postgresql try to run as much vacuum as possible. So if you have 4 databases and the naptime value is 1 min, a vacuum process will run every 20 seconds in a new database.

I hope I'm clear, otherwise feel free to ask some details.

Comment: is that true? Suppose you have 4 db, and there is a big table that need to vacuum, and 20s is not enough,  what happend in the situation?

Comment: Each vacuum is done in its own process. So it is possible that the "vacuum manager" starts another process to vacuum the other table. But there's probably some mechanism somewhere to avoid a too great load on the database, so it is also possible that postgres will wait longer.

Comment: to Krtek:  I am afraid I am not agee with you  in  the second point. Suppose you have 4 db, and suppose thers is no need to do vacuum job beacuse  thers was so less data changed in the 4 db, i think the vaccum will not run every 20 seconds in each db, should be idle instead .

Comment: @francs directly from the documentation "The launcher will distribute the work across time, attempting to start one worker within each database every autovacuum_naptime seconds. (Therefore, if the installation has N databases, a new worker will be launched every autovacuum_naptime/N seconds.)" http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM  For me, it's pretty clear the "launcher" will try to launch a vacuum each `autovacuum_naptime` for each database

Answer (score 2):

It's the minimum time between autovacuum runs. There are quite a few parameters which can decide to run a vacuum but this one sets a minimum "don't do it yet" time so that your database is not continuously running vacuum operations.

Otherwise you may find yourself in a situation where you're continuously vacuuming and no real work gets done :-)

Full details on all the parameters can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html).